# Last Record Of Each Group Using Multiple Joins In Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I Have 3 tables Customer, Bank and BankTransaction.

On My View I want to display each customer with their Balance in the bank account.

Here is my tables

```
   Customer

   Id   Name   
   ---------
   1    John   
   2    Jack 

   Bank

   Id   CustomerId   BankName   
   ----------------------------------
   1    1            HSBC
   2    2            HSBC 

  BankTransaction



   Id   BankID       MoneyIn   MoneyOut  Balance   
   ---------------------------------------------
   1    1            1000      0         1000
   2    1            0         500       500 
   3    2            2000      0         2000 
   4    2            2000      0         4000
   5    2            1000      0         5000
```

Now I want to Display following data view query

```
  John    500
  Jack    5000
```

Last Balance of each customer

Comment: where is customerid in bank transaction

Comment: Each Customer can add his own bank so we do not need it on Bank Transaction. BankId is enough to retrieve data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT A.Name,
       Sum(C.MoneyIN) - Sum(C.MoneyOut) AS Balance
FROM   #Customer A
JOIN   #Bank B ON A.Id = B.id
JOIN   #BankTransaction C ON B.Id = C.BankID
GROUP  BY A.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Window function` you can get the result. Try this.

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Row_number() OVER (partition BY b.id ORDER BY a.id DESC) rn,
                c.Name,
                a.balance
         FROM   BankTransaction a
                JOIN bank b ON a.BankID = b.Id
                JOIN Customer c ON c.Id = b.CustomerId)
SELECT name, balance
FROM   cte
WHERE  rn = 1
```